# Dual boot Windows + Linux boots directly in Windows

Tags: lenovo-laptop, dualboot

I have a Lenovo laptop currently with Windows 11.

I'm trying to add a linux partition but the BIOS doesnt recognize the Linux partition, only that it is a NVMe partition. It is already the first option but it never boots on grub. Doeesn't matter if I use UEFI ou Legacy, if I add the bootloader on the root ("/") or the NVMe partition.

There is no option in the BIOS for me to change to AHCI mode.

Doest anyone know what to do?

Comment: Which bootloader are you using? A good practice for a dual boot setup is to install Windows first and then Linux. Most Linux installations offer an option to install as dual boot. They will use GRUB2 as bootloader and make everything work for you out of the box.

Comment: What model Lenovo? Some have UEFI setting for AHCI under the drive or under the Intel RST line in UEFI settings. Some only use Windows tool to change to AHCI, but you have to first install AHCI drivers into Windows (not sure about Windows 11). Used Intel App in Windows to disable Optane, need AHCI driver in Windows.
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2458373&p=14022735#post14022735 & 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/intel-optane-memory-and-storage-management/9mzng5hzwz1t?activetab=pivot:overviewtab

Comment: Does the version of Linux you are using support working with Secure Boot and UEFI both enabled.

Comment: Also remember you are not “running Windows 11” yet. No one is . It is all subject to change.

Comment: "Most Linux installations offer an option to install as dual boot." Yes, I've tried with Ubuntu, Manjaro and Arco Linux. None of those worked. I've already configured like that in other laptops that I had with no problem but now I don't know what is going on

Comment: "What model Lenovo?" Lenovo Ideapad S145. Thanks, I'll try to search on those references!

Comment: "Also remember you are not “running Windows 11” yet." Yes, you're correct. It was just to clarify that is not Windows 10 default just in case there is any difference.